# Why we need to use "#if defined Identifier" in our C++ header files?

Tags: c++, c

I have a `C++` library header file that starts with below lines of code :

```
#if defined ARRAY_SIZE
#define TABLE_SIZE ARRAY_SIZE
#elif !defined BUFFER_SIZE
#define TABLE_SIZE 128
#else
#define TABLE_SIZE BUFFER_SIZE
#endif
```

**I want to know:**

1. Why do we need to use this lines in our header files?
2. Is the header file the best place to write them? or the library is a better file? (I mean the `.cpp` file that is used by this `.h` file)
3. Where does the processor search, to see if this identifiers (`ARRAY_SIZE` and `BUFFER_SIZE`,in our example) defined already or not? (In the main program? if so, in the lines that is before of including library or in the whole of main program?)

Comment: Refer to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html

Comment: As to why this is necessary: Your posted lines set TABLE_SIZE to some value, why this is necessary depends on the header file /library you are using.  As to your other questions, I'd recommend reading a book or a tutorial about preprocessor macros in c/c++

Comment: @MikeMB Does this check if `TABLE_SIZE` is defined in my `main.cpp` file or not? Does the point of declaration(before #include this library or after that) in the main file matter in the response of this method (`defined()`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preprocessor values are defined with either the `-D` option on the command line sent to the compiler, or by `#define` in the preceding code (including header files included before the section of code you posted). The `defined` preprocessor functionality simply returns `true` (or something interpreted as `true`) when the name given has been defined, or `false` when it has not. Note that the name given must be defined by `#define`, not for example `const int x = 4;` will not be true for `#if defined(x)`. Edit: Note that `defined` never "looks forward". Think of it in terms of old style paper-tape or punch-cards, you can only ever know what you have already seen, not what is in the "future" tape/cards.

Edit: I should add, for completeness, that there are also preprocessor definitions that are done by the compiler - these are providing things like what processor architecture (`__i386__` for 32-bit x86 processors, `__ARM__` for ARM processors, `__x86_64__` for 64-bit x86 processors - and often flags to identify more details of the processor model, such as `__SSE__` or `__MMX__` for those extensions), operating system (`__LINUX__` or `__WINDOWS__` for example - these may also have numeric values that allow you to do something like `#if __WINDOWS__ > 500`) and what compiler such as `__MSVC__` or `__gnuc__`, and a couple of dozen other ones that are more or less cryptic - but the ones in the code fragment in this question is not one of those.

Exactly why this is needed is impossible to explain without knowing which header file you are looking at.

Comment: _.... or by #define in the preceding code (including header files included before the section of code you posted)_ What does this `defined()` method returns if I define my identifier in the `main.cpp` file (That I included this library to it)? Does the point if definition matters?(In lines before of `#include "theLib.h"` or in lines after that)

Comment: @Jean: I've edited to clarify - it is only ever looking "back", never "forward". So whatever has been seen before this point [and think of it as `#include` means "copy the entire content of the named file and paste it in instead of the `#include`]

Comment: This is the main problem :  I have a `main.cpp` ,a `lib.cpp` and a `lib.h` in my computer. The `lib.h` is included in the `main.cpp` file. The problem is that when I compile this program in Windows, the line `defined (TABLE_SIZE BUFFER_SIZE)` in the middle of my `main.cpp` file returns `true`, but when I compile this same program in Linux using `G++`, this line returns `false`! There is no difference between files, but the results are different. Do you have any idea?

Comment: And may I ask you to please add your previous comment to your answer also?

Comment: Without knowing what header files are included before those, I wouldn't know what may be defined or not. Searching for the `TABLE_SIZE` or `BUFFER_SIZE` in the headers prior to your `lib.h` would be key to this. It doesn't sound like something the system headers provide, but you never really know. Not sure which part of my comment you want added - I already added an edit to explain that "it does not look forward, only back" part. How header files work I think is outside of this question (albeit crucial for the understanding of the compile process, of course)

Answer (score 2):

`#if` / `#elif` / `#else` are used for implementing simple logic at *preprocessor* stage. In this example, they are used to correctly set value of `TABLE_SIZE` depending on whether some other values are defined or not.

**Why do we need this?**

Some values are dependant on some other values, as in this example. These other values may be not defined at all - that's why we need to take this into account as well. As `TABLE_SIZE`, `ARRAY_SIZE` etc. are `define`d, changed during compilation, without modifying the code. That's one advantage of using `define`s instead of regular variables. When using `gcc`, you can set `define`s like this:

```
gcc -o test test.c -DBUFFER_SIZE=128
```

This example sets the value of `BUFFER_SIZE` to `128` (unless it's redefined in source code again).

Also, it can be used to create portable code, with some options (or even parts of code) different for various operating systems or architectures.

**Where should preprocessor directives be placed?**

Typically, they are placed in header files. This way it's easier to manage them - you have the same macros set in all files, which include a specific header. Anyway, it's a convention only. Technically, preprocessor directives can be placed anywhere in your code (but before they are used), either in header or source files.

**What is the scope of a macro?**

Proprocessor only performes simple text substitution (and macro expansion of some more complex things, like variable length arguments). A macro can be used after it has been defined, and until it is undefined. Consider the example:

```
/* Here, TEST is not defined. */

#define TEST 123

/* TEST is defined here, and can be used. */

#undef TEST

/* TEST is undefined again, and cannot be used. */
```

When you compile a library or an application, multiple *translation units* can be created. This of them as source files, with all `#include` directives processed. Consider this example:

In `header1.h`:

```
#define TEST 123
```

In `header2.h`:

```
#undef TEST
#define ABC 456
```

In `test.c`:

```
#include "header1.h" /* Defines TEST */

void test1() {
    printf("%d", TEST); /* OK, TEST has been defined in `header1.h`, which is included above. */
}

#include "header2.h" /* Undefines TEST, defines ABC */

void test2() {
    printf("%d", ABC); /* OK, ABC has been defined in `header2.h`, which is included above. */
    /* printf("%d", TEST); */ /* Can't do that - TEST has been undefined! */
}
```

It may be useful at times to check, what the proeprocessor does. For `gcc`, that would be:

```
gcc -E test.c -o test.preprocessed
```

Comment: This is the main problem :  I have a `main.cpp` ,a `lib.cpp` and a `lib.h` in my computer. The `lib.h` is included in the `main.cpp` file. The problem is that when I compile this program in Windows, the line `defined (TABLE_SIZE BUFFER_SIZE)` in the middle of my `main.cpp` file returns `true`, but when I compile this same program in Linux using `G++`, this line returns `false`! There is no difference between files, but the results are different. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure if using `defined` with multiple arguments is valid (I've never seen it being used like this). Have your tried checking `#defined (TABLE_SIZE) && defined (BUFFER_SIZE)`? Other than that, perhaps it's dependant on OS. Are these files Open Source? Can you give us links to them?

Comment: I'll try it and do some edit in the source codes and if the problem doesn't solved I'll post it as a new question. (And about the being OS dependent, I was though about it already. Shall I check equal compilers also?)

Answer (score 1):

The basic logic of that is, for `TABLE_SIZE`:

- if `ARRAY_SIZE` is defined, use that.
- otherwise, if `BUFFER_SIZE` is defined, use that.
- otherwise, use `128`.

As to why you need it, that depends entirely on the code you're looking at.

Whether they're better off in the header file or not depends on how you're going to use it. Generally you would define something like that in a header file if you wanted to use it in a number of different source files. If it's only needed in *one* source file then you could just as easily do it there.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you don't know why you are using hash defines generally it is better to use cpp const as your less likely to run into issues and they are easier to maintain.

That said if you want to to be able to change your TABLE_SIZE between different operating systems/different compiles then hash defines that your using are great.

Answer (score 1):

1. `#if` is a preprocessor directive and `defined` checks whether a certain macro has been defined in this case `ARRAY_SIZE`. If `ARRAY_SIZE` has not been defined the code between #if and #elif will be stripped by the preprocessor thus `TABLE_SIZE` will not be referring to the undefined macro `ARRAY_SIZE` (if you leave the if out it, your code will not signal an error at the macro definition but `TABLE_SIZE` will be literally replaced with `ARRAY_SIZE` wherever it appears in your code and you will end up with some fairly cryptic error messages elsewhere).

   Thus `#if` is a useful construct to do compile time checks and
   changes to  code depending on the platform where the code is
   compiled or depending on some parameter.
2. Declarations are usually in header files (.h) whereas definitions are in .cpp files. Thus `#if` is mostly used in the header files but can appear anywhere
3. The preprocessor searches up to what it has processed till that point meaning that if a file containing the definition of `ARRAY_SIZE` had been included before your header, `ARRAY_SIZE` would be defined at that point i.e. as you said in the lines that is before including the library.